# AWS SSM Policy doesn't work like the documentation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I tried to provide a policy following the samples here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/getting-started-restrict-access-examples.html

But, I keep getting a warning and it does not work.

These are all I tried so far:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowStartSessionExceptProd",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:StartSession"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "ssm:resourceTag/environment": [
                        "prod",
                        "Prod"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Or

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowStartSessionExceptProd",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:StartSession"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance": [
                        "i-myInstanceId1",
                        "i-myInstanceId2"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Or even I tried to use more resource-based conditions.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowStartSessionExceptProd",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:StartSession"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "ssm:resourceTag/environment": [
                        "prod",
                        "Prod"
                    ],
                    "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:resourceTag/environment": [
                        "prod",
                        "Prod"
                    ],
                    "ec2:resourceTag/environment": [
                        "prod",
                        "Prod"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In general, all I want to do is allow access to start session in SSM on servers which are not prod servers.
My EC2 prod servers all have a tag `environment:prod`

I get an error message on each condition which doesn't work:
`There are no actions in your policy that support this condition key.`

Example:

`ec2:resourceTag /environment (StringNotLike prod and Prod)
There are no actions in your policy that support this condition key.`

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you also provide the warning please.

Comment: @AlexK. Sure. It's been added

Comment: Could you please refer to this document: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-policy-summaries-now-help-you-identify-errors-and-correct-permissions-in-your-iam-policies/ and provide a screenshot with the Error there.

Comment: I think I found it, the action `ssm:StartSession` isn't applicable for condition `ec2:resourceTag` or `ssm:resourceTag`. Find the screenshot here: https://imgur.com/xdAgJQC .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments and some investigation, here's the answer:

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_awssystemsmanager.html#awssystemsmanager-document), it is pretty easy to notice which **actions** support what conditions.

Unfortunately the examples provided for Restricting Access are wrong, i.e. there's an error in the documentation that contains the sample code.

A PR might be a good idea so others don't hang on the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like you are right. Let me do more investigation though. If confirmed, you have bounty ;)

Comment: Same issue on a different code snippet, though this one may not be AWS' fault: using an asymmetric KMS key, you cannot include the `kms:EncryptionContext` Condition; that's in the docs, which are written for symmetric key (that I found, at least). This put me on the right path!